# css get whichever is smaller: width or height

Tags: html, css

I'm using the https://github.com/nimiq/qr-scanner for scanning QR codes. It uses a smaller rectangle from the whole video for scanning the codes.

This rectangle is a centered square of two thirds of the video width or height, whichever is smaller.

I want to show a div with red border to show the user where is this scan region. How can I do it in css without calculating the top, left, width and height in JS?

Comment: actually I think it's possible but only relative to the Viewport dimensons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you want, but I think this may give you some hints. 40% of the viewport shorter size. You can fix percentage by changing value of the `--side` which is a CSS variable ex. `--side: min(30vw, 30vh)` will be 30% of the sorter side

```css
#container{
  width:calc(100vw -2px);
  height:calc(100vh -2px);
  border:1px solid #ccc; 
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}
#scan_rect {
  --side: min(40vw, 40vh);
  height: var(--side);
  width: var(--side);
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: calc((100vh - var(--side)) / 2) calc((100vw - var(--side)) / 2);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="scan_rect"></div>
</div>
```